# Is $F(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x)}f\,d\lambda$ Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ Lebesgue integrable. Is
$$F(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x)}f\,d\lambda$$
Lispchitz continuous? where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I think $F$ is not necessarily Lipschitz continuous. I tried with the functions $\chi_{[1,\infty)}x^{-2/3}$, $\chi_{(0,\infty)}x^{1/2}$ where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$, and other combinations but non of them gives me a counterexample. Any suggestion?

Comment: $F$ is absolutely continuous, that is given $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for any measurable set $A$, $\lambda(A)<\delta$ implies $\int_A|f|<\varepsilon$. This gives you in particular uniform continuity. As for Lipschitz, you may try with an integral function that every now and them takes large values. $\sum_n n^2\mathbb{1}_{(n-\tfrac{1}{n^3},n+\tfrac{1}{n^3})}$.

Comment: Okay, that function is not integrable but changing $n^3$  by $n^4$ it is integrable. Now, how is it that $F(x)$  is not Lipschitz? @OliverDiaz

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, but the $3$ kept creeping in... try something like that. I think that will do the trick (in a way of a counter example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f\in L_1(\lambda)$ and set $F(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x]}f(t)\,dt$.
If $F$ is Lipschitz over $\mathbb{R}$, then for some constant $L$
$$\frac{|F(y)-F(x)|}{|y-x|}\leq L$$
for all $x\neq y$. As $F$ is differentiable at every Lebesgue point of $f$, and $F'=f$ at such points, then
$|F'(x)|=|f(x)|\leq L$  almost surely; hence $\|f\|_\infty<\infty$

It follows that any $f\in L_1(\lambda)$ which is not in $L_\infty(\lambda)$, $F$ will not be Lipschitz over the whole real line. Here are two examples:

1. $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(|x|)$ is in $L_1$
2. $g(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=1}n\mathbb{1}_{(n-2^{-n},n+2^{-n}]}(x)$